# Choosing a WiFi antenna for outdoor robot

Tags: mobile-robot, wifi

A time has come for my robot to get some more permanent computer than my laptop balanced on top of it.
I have selected a mini itx board that can be powered directly from battery and some components that go with it including a wifi card and now I'm thinking about the antenna I will need.

Constraints I have identified so far:

- The robot's body is a closed aluminium box, so I think this rules out keeping the antenna inside.
- The robot is intended to work outdoors, so it needs to be waterproof.
- Vibrations might be an issue.

And the questions:

- What parameters should I watch when selecting an antenna?
- Is it ok to use indoor stick antenna and seal the mounting point with hot glue?
- Does it change anything if the antenna will be sticking out of largish sheet of alluminium?
- The robot will also have GPS, is it possible that the two will interact badly under some circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What parameters should I watch when selecting an antenna?

The biggest one is going to be the application, does it need to operate outside? in pouring rain? does it need to be omnidirectional?

> Is it ok to use indoor stick antenna and seal the mounting point with hot glue?

Generally this will work just fine depending on how harsh the environment, outside on a sunny day? will probably be just fine, outside 24/7 in all weather? you will probably need something rated for ingress and UV exposure.

> Does it change anything if the antenna will be sticking out of largish sheet of aluminum?

No It might cause minor interference, just be sure the antenna is isolated form the enclosure.

> The robot will also have GPS, is it possible that the two will interact badly under some circumstances?

Nope they use different signal bands so they will not interfere, however placing the GPS receiver inside a medal box could cause many issues